# Необработанное исключение в "0x01376163" в "OpenGL.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x000002a4"

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

```
#include <iostream> 
#define GLEW_STATIC 
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 

const GLint WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 50; 

int main() { 
glfwInit(); 

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE); 

GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); 

int screanWidth, screanHeight; 
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screanWidth, &screanHeight); 

if (nullptr == window) { 
std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl; 
glfwTerminate(); 

return EXIT_FAILURE; 
} 

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); 

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 

if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) { 
std::cout << "Failed to initialise GLEW" << std::endl; 
return EXIT_FAILURE; 
} 

glViewport(0, 0, screanWidth, screanHeight); 

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) { 
glfwPollEvents(); 

glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
} 

glfwTerminate(); 

return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Показывает что ошибка в:

```
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screanWidth, &screanHeight);
```

[image: введите сюда код]

Comment: Илья, вы могли бы отметить галочкой вопрос, который вам помог.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно проблема в проверке успешности вызова функции `glfwCreateWindow` уже после использования потенциально нулевого указателя `window`. Результат `glfwInit` тоже необходимо обязательно проверять до вызова других библиотечных функций.

Comment: я вообще только не давно взялся за изучение, не подскажите как прописать эту проверку для glfwInit?

Comment: @ИльяДударь 1) открываете документацию к этой функции. 2) смотрите, какая процедура необходима для проверки успешности вызова этой функции 3) реализуете эту процедуру в коде. Надо полагать, в случае с `glfwInit` проверка будет заключаться в тривиальном сравнении возвращаемого значения с нулем

Answer (score 2):

Все разобрался! выявил ошибку через этот код

```
int code = glfwGetError(NULL);
if(code != GLFW_NO_ERROR)
std::cout<<code<<std::end;
```

0x00010006 что означает! Установленный графический драйвер не поддерживает запрошенный API или не поддерживает его через выбранный сервер создания контекста.
Некоторые предустановленные графические драйверы Windows не поддерживают OpenGL. Ну в моем случае дело в видеокарте из мезозойского периода)))))) которая не поддерживает новый OpenGL